# Angular async custom validator for Password match doest working in my login form

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to make a custom validator for my form but I have some problems with the return.

my form:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.signinForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  userName:[null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
  userEmail:[null, [Validators.email,Validators.required], [this.noteValidators.emailCheckValidator(true)]],
  userPassword: this.formBuilder.group({
    password:[null, Validators.required],
    repeat:[null, Validators.required]
  }, {validator: this.noteValidators.checkMatchPassword()})
})}
```

My validators are in a service. 
I have one custom validator working, and I trying to make the other like this:
Custom Validator OK:

```
public emailCheckValidator(exists:boolean) : AsyncValidatorFn {

    return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<{[key: string]: any } | null> => { 
      return control.valueChanges.pipe(
        debounceTime(500),
        take(1),
        switchMap( () => this.httpNote.checkEmail(control.value).pipe(
          map( res => {
            if(res == exists ){
              return { checkEmail: res };
            }
            return null;
          })
        ))
      )
    }
  }
```

and the validator with the bug:

```
public checkMatchPassword():AsyncValidatorFn {

    return (group:FormGroup): Observable<{[key:string]: any} | null> =>{

      return group.valueChanges.pipe(
        debounceTime(500),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        take(1),
        map( (res) => {
              console.log(res);
              if(group.get('password').value === group.get('repeat').value) {
                return null;
              } 
              return  { passwordMatch: false };
          }
        )
      )//pipe
    }
  }
```

Is there another approach to writing custom validators without HTTP requests>

My only condition is to organize all the validators into a service.

Comment: Is there a reason that this needs to be an async validator? Doesn't seem to make much sense to me? The problem here is likely the `take` operator which will complete the source observable after the first notification. Afterward, all value changes are ignored

Comment: No, dont need to be an async validator. I only want to organize all the validators in the service. 
to be honest, i still have some confusion on the concepts of async validators and Observables, but im studying all this.